# filter a multiindex dataframe bassed on condition from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd appreciate your help.

I have a multiindex dataframe like this:

```
df1 = {'Sex': {('002_S_0413', 0, 'DTI'): 'F',
  ('002_S_0413', 0, 'T1'): 'F',
  ('002_S_4213', 2, 'DTI'): 'F',
  ('002_S_4213', 2, 'T1'): 'F',
  ('002_S_4799', 0, 'DTI'): 'M',
  ('002_S_4799', 0, 'T1'): 'M',
  ('002_S_5178', 0, 'DTI'): 'M',
  ('002_S_5178', 0, 'T1'): 'M',
  ('002_S_5230', 2, 'DTI'): 'F',
  ('002_S_5230', 2, 'T1'): 'F'},
 'DIAGNOSIS': {('002_S_0413', 0, 'DTI'): 1.0,
  ('002_S_0413', 0, 'T1'): 1.0,
  ('002_S_4213', 2, 'DTI'): 1.0,
  ('002_S_4213', 2, 'T1'): 1.0,
  ('002_S_4799', 0, 'DTI'): 1.0,
  ('002_S_4799', 0, 'T1'): 1.0,
  ('002_S_5178', 0, 'DTI'): 1.0,
  ('002_S_5178', 0, 'T1'): 1.0,
  ('002_S_5230', 2, 'DTI'): 1.0,
  ('002_S_5230', 2, 'T1'): 1.0}}
```

and a second dataframe:

```
df2 = {'Subject ID': {0: '002_S_0413',
  1: '002_S_0413',
  2: '002_S_4213',
  3: '002_S_4213',
  4: '002_S_4799',
  5: '002_S_4799',
  6: '002_S_4799',
  7: '002_S_5178',
  8: '002_S_5178',
  9: '002_S_5230',
  10: '002_S_5230',
  11: '002_S_5230',
  12: '002_S_6007',
  13: '002_S_6007'},
 'Visit_NUM': {0: 0,
  1: 2,
  2: 0,
  3: 2,
  4: 0,
  5: 1,
  6: 2,
  7: 0,
  8: 2,
  9: 0,
  10: 1,
  11: 2,
  12: 0,
  13: 1}}
```

I want to filter `df1`:
if for each correspondant `Subject ID` (level=0) in both dataframes there is a `Visit_NUM` in `df2` that is greater than or equal to 2 plus that in `df1` (level=1), keep it (the subject's row in df1), if not delete it.

To clarify: for each `Subject ID`, if (Visit_NUM_in_df1) >= (2 + Visit_NUM_in_df2) keep that Subject's row in df1, if not delete it.

This is what I've done:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df1.reset_index([
    'Visit_NUM', 'Description']).groupby(
    level=0)['Visit_NUM'].transform(lambda x: x + 2)).reset_index(
).drop_duplicates(['Subject ID'])

t = df3.merge(df2.reset_index(), on=['Subject ID', 'Visit_NUM'])
t = t['Subject ID']
out = df1.loc[df1.index.get_level_values('Subject ID').isin(t)]
```

The result would be something like:

```
out = {'Sex': {('002_S_0413', 0, 'DTI'): 'F',
  ('002_S_0413', 0, 'T1'): 'F',
  ('002_S_4799', 0, 'DTI'): 'M',
  ('002_S_4799', 0, 'T1'): 'M',
  ('002_S_5178', 0, 'DTI'): 'M',
  ('002_S_5178', 0, 'T1'): 'M'},
 'DIAGNOSIS': {('002_S_0413', 0, 'DTI'): 1.0,
  ('002_S_0413', 0, 'T1'): 1.0,
  ('002_S_4799', 0, 'DTI'): 1.0,
  ('002_S_4799', 0, 'T1'): 1.0,
  ('002_S_5178', 0, 'DTI'): 1.0,
  ('002_S_5178', 0, 'T1'): 1.0}}
```

By doing what I've done I'm just getting those that have Visit_NUM + 2, but not those that are >= (Visit_NUM + 2).

Also, I believe there is an easy way to do this, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend has helped me with this answer:

```
list_subjects = np.unique(df1.reset_index()['Subject ID'])

tt=[]
for i in range(len(list_subjects)):
    name = list_subjects[i]
    visit = df2[df2['Subject ID'] == name]['Visit_NUM']
    visit_min = np.unique(df1.loc[name].reset_index()['Visit_NUM'])
    if any(visit >= visit_min[0]+2):
        tt.append(name)
        
out = df1.loc[df1.index.get_level_values('Subject ID').isin(tt)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
max_visit_num = df2.groupby('Subject ID')['Visit_NUM'].max()
out = df1.loc[df1.index.get_level_values(0).isin(max_visit_num[max_visit_num >= 2].index)]
```

Comment: thanks, but this code is getting those Subjects in df1 whose visit_num in df2 is >=2, but what I want is to get those in df1 whose visit_num in df2 is  >= (visit_num_df1 + 2 ). So if df1 has a visit_num of say 3, I would select it iff it it has a value >=5 in df2